# How do I add a List to an anonymous object in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-objects

Let's say I have a list:

```
var list = new List<int>{1,2,3};
```

How do I add this to an anonymous object such that the object would look like:

```
{ list : [1,2,3] }
```

Comment: Do you mean it would look like this when you serialize it to a JSON?

Comment: whats' wrong with `var list = new List<int>{1,2,3}; var myObj = new { list };`

Comment: Yes I wanted to serialize it to JSON. Thanks for the answers, when I was reading documentation I didn't realize I could just do `new {list = list}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating the anonymous object:

```
var anon = new { list }
```

I assume that by saying you want it to look like this:

```
{ list : [1,2,3] }
```

you are talking about the output of a JSON serialization, in which it would look like once you serialize.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = new 
{
    list = list
};
```

`obj` is now an anonymous object with a property called `list` of type `List<int>`.

Comment: Or just `new { list }`